# Hadoop map reduce Extract specific columns from csv file in csv format

Tags: java, hadoop, file-io, mapreduce, bigdata

I am new to hadoop and working on a big data project where I have to clean and filter given csv file.
like if given csv file has 200 columns then I need to select only 20 specific columns (so called data filtering) as a output for further operation.
also as a part of data cleaning, I have to check for correct date format for date columns and change all format to a single format like DD-MM-YYYY.

So far I am able to read given file, but can you please suggest as how to select specific columns and also about checking for date formats ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use Apache Pig to do Filtering and Validating Date format as well. Follow below steps :

1. Copy your file into HDFS
2. Load file using load command and pigStorage().
3. Select 20 column using ForEach statment (You can just give column name/number like $0,$3,$5..etc)
4. Write UDF to validate date format ( Ref -http://www.crackinghadoop.com/pig-java-udf-validate-date-format/)
5. Store Your filtered output using 'store'.

Comment: You can use map reduce also for filtering and validation. Select your 20 column in mapper and validate dateformat in reducer.